# Door Not Closing All The Way

Tags: doors, door-frame, hinges, frame

I replaced the hinges on a interior (bedroom) door, and now the door will not close all the way.  When I removed the old hinges/screws nothing jumped out at me that was unusual.  No exceptionally long screws, no strange brackets/braces etc.

### **EDIT**

If I remove the middle hinge, and remove the strike plate, the door will close as expected. Seems that it is catching lower than it was before with the new hinges... --- What do I need to do with the middle hinge so that the door will close with it on?
**END EDIT**

These images are what I get when I try to close the door.  What should I do to try to remedy this?

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

**EDIT**Hinge Images
[image: hinge]
[image: hinge]
[image: hinge]

**Edit 2**Old Hinge is Gold, New Hinge is Dark...they are close to the same size as I was able to use same holes to attach the new hinges...

[image: Hinge Comparison]

Comment: Pictures of where the hinges are attached would be most useful. If the new hinges are slimmer or even have the fulcrum offset from that of the old ones, you might need to either shim them out, or move them slightly outward from the current attach point.

Comment: Edited to show hinge images

Comment: Thanks - but as they're black hinges & low-res photos, that's really hard to see. Could you try light it so we can see the relative height of the hinges compared to the frame they're attached to. There's a vague hint they might be squeezing & need dropping deeper, or that the fulcrum may be further into the frame [we'll never be able to see that without old & new hinges side by side for comparison] but there's definite evidence the door is trapping into the frame on your 3rd image - we now need to figure out *why*.

Comment: Take off the new middle hinge. Compare its thickness when closed to the old hinge. Chances are your new hinge is thicker than the old. Please report back and we can help fix it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - see if those pics with a flash help out

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - hinges appear to be same thickness.  I've added these hinges to three four other doors issue free, just this one is giving me trouble.

Comment: It looks like the hinge wasn't gotten all the way into the notch out, so the leaves are jammed while closing. After installation, the hinge shall be smooth/flat with the wood.

Comment: @r13 - meaning I should take the hinge off and try to "re-seat" it into the proper grove of the previous hinge?

Comment: If @r13 is right, you could just whack the hinge with a hammer (put a block of wood between to avoid marring the hinge) to seat it completely into the mortise. Then tighten the screws again.

Comment: Yes. After removing the hinge, clean the seating thoroughly using a fine grit sand cloth, as there are usually have small bumps around the holes.

Comment: @r13 - if i remove the middle hinge, and remove the strike plate, the door will close as expected.  Seems that it is catching lower than it was before with the new hinges... --- What do I need to do with the middle hinge so that the door will close with it on?

Comment: Sounds like either one of the hinges is too low (deep into the seating) or propped up too high above the wood surface. You should use a level to make sure both wood surfaces are straight and vertical, before and after installing the hinges. (temporarily install hinges to the door, or the frame, only to check the straightness after hinge installation)

Comment: in any way would tightening the screws help at all?  They are in all the way, but if I got a longer one and replaced one of the screws with the longer one would that fix it?